# Django + Heroku + Mandrill mail_admins() not working, either manually or as triggered by 500 error

Tags: python, django, mandrill

I have a Django (v1.4) site on Heroku using Mandrill for SMTP. I have all the required values in my settings file:

- EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD
- EMAIL_HOST_USER
- EMAIL_HOST
- EMAIL_PORT
- SERVER_EMAIL (set to a real address, not root@localhost)

I can send regular emails just fine using `send_messages()` manually from the client. But no emails are sent when for 500 errors and calling `mail_admins` in the client doesn't produce any errors but also doesn't send an email.

Here is my logging setup:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}
```

And my ADMINS:

```
ADMINS = (
    ('My Name', 'myaddress@gmail.com'),
)
```

I've checked my Spam folder and there is nothing there. Am I missing something in settings? Or something else?

Comment: What does the error log say?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Have you checked your Mandrill API logs?

I am having the same issue and noticed that the emails are being sent to the Mandrill API (since I set my smtp settings for Mandrill in settings.py), but that the from_email and from_name are empty in the API calls.

So, I found https://github.com/brack3t/Djrill and am about to install it. I'll let you know if it "just works".

EDIT: So after installing djrill and following the documentation I'm getting failed API calls for error messages - the from_email is showing as "root@localhost" for some reason.

When I do the shell test shown on the github page (with an email from an accepted domain for my Mandrill account replacing Djrill Sender), it works:

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail

send_mail("It works!", "This will get sent through Mandrill",
    "Djrill Sender <djrill@example.com>", ["to@example.com"])
```

It turns out that I had my default "From" email setting name confused. Its called SERVER_EMAIL. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/settings/#std:setting-SERVER_EMAIL.

**So the following in settings.py fixed my issue**:

```
SERVER_EMAIL = myname@myMandrillApprovedDomain.com
```

Comment: Yes, missing SERVER_MAIL settings was definitely the problem.